# Microsoft visual studio screen problem

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having a problem thats not about the code, it's about the screen in Microsoft visual studio 2008.

Actually problem is i created one utility from couple of weeks i didn't opened that utility today i opened (in Microsoft visual studio the screen appearing blank no controls are visible in that.But all the controls properties are there. I tried a lot but i didn't get solution. Last when the same thing happened i created the controls again. Now i don't want to go to create all the controls again. If any one have the solution please help me.

Before screen is like this:

[image: Bofore page]

Now its blank (like new page)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Please provide screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I'm not sure if this is a application/code build issue or an IDE issue, what you could try is to reset the settings in visual studio and see if this helps.

You can do this by going to Tools -> Import/Export settings and then following the wizard to reset the settings, you may also want to perform a backup before resetting them (this is also part of the wizard) then they can be restored if this causes you further issues.

I don't have a copy of 2008 available at the moment so some menu entries may be slightly named different.

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Now there is more information, this looks like there may be a problem with the code in the

```
InitializeComponent
```

method of the form.designer file (e.g. if you are using c# this would be something like Form1.Designer.cs and can be found by expanding the corresponding form in the solution explorer), if you remove/comment the lines that say

```
this.Controls.Add(this.NameOfControl)
```

(NameOfControl is where you would see your declared controls name)

then you get the behaviour that you are seeing, the controls do not render as they are never added to the forms controls collection but as they are declared you will still see them in the properties drop down and wont be able to add another control with the same name.

Comment: but the problem not with all screens only one screen is changed

Comment: By screen, do you mean the form or the pc display?

Comment: this is my form before its looking like this. Today when i opened i'm getting blank screen, but in property window all control properties are there and if i try to create a control with the same name its giving error so controls are there but they are not visible